# How to install the latest Docker .deb package?

Tags: docker

On our production Ubuntu servers we are not allowed to make changes to the apt sources lists.

So, using the script located at https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/ is unfortunately not an option for me. Instead I need to download the docker .deb package for ubuntu and install it manually using dpkg.

However the docker installation documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#installing-docker-on-ubuntu does not detail how to get the deb package directly. Any ideas?

Comment: http://get.docker.io/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lxc-docker/lxc-docker_1.6.2_amd64.deb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up installing docker like so using direct deb package downloads:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker_version=1.6.2
get_docker=https://get.docker.io/ubuntu/pool/main/l

for package in lxc-docker lxc-docker-$docker_version; do
    deb=${package}_${docker_version}_amd64.deb
    curl -s $get_docker/$package/$deb -o $deb
done

sudo dpkg -i lxc-docker_${docker_version}_amd64.deb lxc-docker-${docker_version}_${docker_version}_amd64.deb
```

(Thanks to @eldos for pointing me in the right direction)

Comment: there are 5 dep packages (each with multiple versions) in https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/arm64/ .. which ones should i download for fresh docker installation ?

Answer (score 5):

Latest docker packages (post 1.9) are now avaiable at https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/pool/main/d/docker-engine/

You can download the one that suits your OS & architecture from here and install with 'sudo dpkg -i < package_name >'

Comment: site is down now